# Cómo calcular numero menor y mayor?

Tags: java

¿Cómo podria hacer para calcular el numero menor de forma dinámica aca? Estoy teniendo un error de que, por ejemplo, al poner para calcular 2 números me calcula 3 y no me calcula bien a veces el mayor y el menor dependiendo de la forma que los introduzco:

```
int numeros;
System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
numeros = lector.nextInt();
System.out.println("Introduce " + numeros + " sueldos");
int sueldo;
int numeroMayor = 0;
int numeroMenor;
numeroMenor = lector.nextInt();
for(int i = 1 ; i <= numeros;i++){
   sueldo = lector.nextInt();
   if(sueldo > numeroMayor){
       numeroMayor = sueldo;
   }


   if(sueldo < numeroMenor){
       numeroMenor = sueldo;
   } 


}   
System.out.println("El sueldo mayor de los introducidos es " + numeroMayor);
System.out.println("El sueldo menor de los introducidos es " + numeroMenor);
```

Comment: El problema de que te esté pidiendo un número de más es porque haces `numeroMenor = lector.nextInt();` antes del bucle `for` . De todas formas, creo que tal y como lo tienes planteado no te va a funcionar. Por ejemplo, piensa que si metes todos los números negativos te va a decir que el mayor es cero porque has inicializado la variable `numeroMayor` a cero.

Lo ideal sería que trabajaras con `arrays`. Veo que estás aprendiendo, por lo que no sé si has llegado a ese punto.

Comment: cierto, realizas la entrada de datos demasiadas veces.

Comment: Solo modifica el `<=` por `<`,  `for(int i=1; i<numeros; i++)`, porque el programa ya leyó el primer sueldo afuera del ciclo.

Comment: Pero eso sigue sin resolver el problema de los valores negativos

Answer (score 1):

Como mostrar el número más alto y el más bajo de un grupo de números:

```
package pruebas;

public class MinorAndMaior {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] numbers = {1,5,7};
        MinorAndMaior mm = new MinorAndMaior();
        mm.showMinorAnMaior(numbers);
    }

    public void showMinorAnMaior(int[] numbers) {
        System.out.println("The minor number is: " + this.getMinor(numbers));
        System.out.println("The maior number is: " + this.getMaior(numbers));
    }

    private int getMaior(int a, int b) {

        if (a>b) {
            return a;
        }
        return b;
    }

    private int getMaior(int[] numbers) {

        int result = numbers[0];
        for (int n: numbers) {
            result = this.getMaior(result, n);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private int getMinor(int a, int b) {

        if (a<b) {
            return a;
        }
        return b;
    }

    private int getMinor(int[] numbers) {

        int result = numbers[0];
        for (int n: numbers) {
            result = this.getMinor(result, n);
        }

        return result;
    }

} // class
```

Resultado:

```
The minor number is: 1
The maior number is: 7
```

Answer (score 1):

**Para poder sabes cuál es el menor y el mayor debes hacer lo siguiente:**

1. El número mayor debe inicializarse con el menor valor posible. (Al comparar la primera vez cualquier número podría ser mayor)
2. El número menor debe inicializarse con el mayor valor posible.(Al comparar la primera vez cualquier número podría ser menor)
3. Capturas el valor del número cada vez que entré en la estructura repetitiva (bucle)
4. Si el **número** es mayor al último valor de **mayor** entonces se asigna el número como el valor **mayor**.
5. Si el **número** es menor al último valor de **menor** entonces se asigna el número como el valor **menor**.

   ```
   Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
   int numeros;
   System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
   numeros = lector.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Introduce " + numeros + " sueldos");
   int numero;
   int mayor = -999999999;
   int menor = 999999999;
   for(int i = 0 ; i < numeros;i++)
   {           
       numero = lector.nextInt();

       if(numero > mayor) //Comparar si el número es mayor al valor de la variable mayor
          mayor = numero; //Si cumple entonces el número se convierte en el nuevo valor mayor

       if(numero < menor) //Comparar si el número es menor al valor de la variable menor

          menor = numero; //Si cumple entonces el número se convierte en el nuevo valor menor
   }   

   System.out.println("El número mayor de los introducidos es " + mayor);
   System.out.println("El número menor de los introducidos es " + menor);
   ```